# link interno do react

Tags: react

como faço para lincar do menu atravez do id a um componente utilizando o react?

Sobre

```
    <a  href="#Tecnologias">
      <li>Tecnologias</li>
    </a>

    <a href="#Projetos">
      <li>Projetos</li>
    </a>

    <a href="#Contato">
      <li>Contato</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
```

utilizando link não de certo !
<

Answer (score 0):

Fala Adriano pra linkar uma tag <a> com um outro elemento na mesma página basta colocar um ID no elemento alvo e no href passar esse link.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#courses">Courses</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<h2 id="about">About</h2>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione neque at
  debitis aperiam excepturi doloribus quos molestias magni sequi libero
  repudiandae explicabo illum, a earum itaque nisi enim delectus dicta sunt
  esse. Nisi, possimus praesentium consequuntur quo aut perferendis numquam
  nesciunt facilis earum perspiciatis voluptatem consectetur doloremque,
  vitae dolorem explicabo vel eveniet, provident autem maxime sunt at!
  Beatae, quos nemo cumque, aspernatur deserunt atque odit dignissimos
  tempora corrupti repellat quae, officiis sed id nisi nostrum dolorum. Modi
  iste magni distinctio nostrum. Impedit consectetur perferendis eaque
  consequatur praesentium, corporis, vero magni eius itaque nulla similique
  quaerat alias sit ea nostrum. Dolore, voluptatem debitis dolorem vel ut,
  molestiae doloremque excepturi dolorum, nobis voluptate quasi. Vero itaque
  a iusto illum accusantium libero cumque culpa facere asperiores molestiae
  numquam, nihil architecto delectus, quas ex atque iste earum reiciendis?
  Voluptatem, nam sunt soluta numquam non saepe, culpa totam quos
  dignissimos minima perferendis. Veniam laboriosam blanditiis facilis
  quidem sit ipsum earum aliquam eveniet culpa voluptates minus perspiciatis
  fugiat iste eligendi corrupti nam, unde quaerat iusto, fuga quos velit hic
  praesentium numquam. Blanditiis, amet id quas reiciendis repellendus
  dolores cumque ullam, enim quod asperiores odio quae aperiam non
  accusantium voluptatum! Earum minus hic sequi repudiandae deleniti
  impedit!
</p>
<h2 id="courses">Courses</h2>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione neque at
  debitis aperiam excepturi doloribus quos molestias magni sequi libero
  repudiandae explicabo illum, a earum itaque nisi enim delectus dicta sunt
  esse. Nisi, possimus praesentium consequuntur quo aut perferendis numquam
  nesciunt facilis earum perspiciatis voluptatem consectetur doloremque,
  vitae dolorem explicabo vel eveniet, provident autem maxime sunt at!
  Beatae, quos nemo cumque, aspernatur deserunt atque odit dignissimos
  tempora corrupti repellat quae, officiis sed id nisi nostrum dolorum. Modi
  iste magni distinctio nostrum. Impedit consectetur perferendis eaque
  consequatur praesentium, corporis, vero magni eius itaque nulla similique
  quaerat alias sit ea nostrum. Dolore, voluptatem debitis dolorem vel ut,
  molestiae doloremque excepturi dolorum, nobis voluptate quasi. Vero itaque
  a iusto illum accusantium libero cumque culpa facere asperiores molestiae
  numquam, nihil architecto delectus, quas ex atque iste earum reiciendis?
  Voluptatem, nam sunt soluta numquam non saepe, culpa totam quos
  dignissimos minima perferendis. Veniam laboriosam blanditiis facilis
  quidem sit ipsum earum aliquam eveniet culpa voluptates minus perspiciatis
  fugiat iste eligendi corrupti nam, unde quaerat iusto, fuga quos velit hic
  praesentium numquam. Blanditiis, amet id quas reiciendis repellendus
  dolores cumque ullam, enim quod asperiores odio quae aperiam non
  accusantium voluptatum! Earum minus hic sequi repudiandae deleniti
  impedit!
</p>
```

Comment: então mas com react como seria feito da mesma forma mas react-router-dom utlizando <Link/>

Answer (score -1):

import { Link } from 'react-scroll';

```
    </Link>
```

dessa forma funcionou muito bem e ainda deu pra animar o scroll`<Link to="Tecnologias" spy={true} smooth={true} offset={90} duration={1000} > Tecnologias`

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).